# python reorder dictionary based on a combination of values

Tags: python

I am trying to write a targeting priority script for an AI. My goal is to rank targets based on their score of `damage_per_shot / rate_of_fire` and reorder the list based on highest targeting priority. I finally hit an error I didn't know how to work around however. `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

I am very new to Python and built this mostly by Googling the terms I would have used in Ruby. I would also appreciate suggestions about how to do this in the correct Python "style" if I made any major errors.

```
enemyList=[{"id":1,"damage_per_shot":10,"rate_of_fire":2},{"id":3,"damage_per_shot":0,"rate_of_fire":0},{"id":2,"damage_per_shot":14,"rate_of_fire":2}]
#enemyList=unit_client.ask_nearest_enemy()

print(enemyList)
aDict = {}
for item in enemyList:
    if(item["rate_of_fire"]!=0):
        currScore=float(item["damage_per_shot"]/item["rate_of_fire"])
    aDict[item['id']] = currScore   

def focus_fire2(data=None, *args, **kawargs):
    print("===ff2===")
    target_id=sorted(aDict, key=data.get)
    print(target_id)
    print("attacking: "+str(id))
    #unit_client.do_attack(key)
    ##remove item from list
    if(len(aDict)>0):
        del aDict[target_id] #remove the object from the dict after done
        print(aDict)
        focus_fire2()
    else:
        return 0
    #unit_client.when_item_destroyed(target, aDict.pop(key,None)) 
    #unit_client.when_item_destroyed(target, focus_fire2) 
focus_fire2()
```

The traceback looks like

```
[{'damage_per_shot': 10, 'id': 1, 'rate_of_fire': 2}, {'damage_per_shot': 0, 'id
': 3, 'rate_of_fire': 0}, {'damage_per_shot': 14, 'id': 2, 'rate_of_fire': 2}]
===ff2===
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ffire.py", line 26, in <module>
    focus_fire2()
  File "ffire.py", line 13, in focus_fire2
    target_id=sorted(aDict, key=data.get)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full error/traceback

Comment: I do notice that you have 'data.get' in your focus_fire2 function, and in the arguments you set data to None by default. If you didn't specifically set  data to something like focus_fire2(data=something), then the error makes sense...

Comment: @Paul Rooney, Thanks for including the traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
sorted(aDict, key=data.get)
```

by

```
sorted(aDict, key=aDict.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `focus_fire2`, you set `data` to `None` by default in the arguments of the function definition. Unless you set it to something other than `None` when you call it, like `focus_fire2(data=something)`, then it's equal to `None` when you do, `data.get()` later on. And there lies your error I think. You are treating a `NoneType` like a `dict`. If you're calling `get` on it, you probably should be setting it equal to some `dict` or other.

Comment: so `aDict` isnt known inside the function? Would I solve this by making it a global variable? of by passing it to the function somehow?

Comment: based on your edit, If I set `data=dict` I tell the function to expect all dictionaries, or do I set it to `aDict` specifically?

Comment: aDict should be known alright, it's data that's your problem I think. It's set to None, and you are calling a dictionary method on it(get)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want target_id to look like?

Comment: @Rilcon42 Do you just want a sorted list of the id's?

Comment: My goal is to sort the dict by value so the highest value is first, then do something with the id (in this case the key to the key/value pair)

Answer (score 0):

You get an error, because run function without arguments, and by default data have a `None` type. And for me it's not good idea, set default value as None for non optional arguments. You need run function with argument `focus_fire2(aDict)`, or change `target_id=sorted(aDict, key=data.get)` to `target_id=sorted(aDict, key=aDict.get, reverse=True)` you get in `target_id`, list of sorted key from `aDict`, where first value is higher. But `target_id` is a list and this code is wrong `del aDict[target_id]`. What must be in `target_id`?